# A `graphics` object works well by itself but doesn't work with `Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center`, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm trying to center a circle in a given rectangle. One of the approaches to do the job could be `graphics` working with `Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center` and I'm having trouble doing that. Here is the code.

```js
class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({
      key: 'BootScene'
    });
  }
  create() {
    let btn = this.add.rectangle(800, 600, 200, 150, '#000').setOrigin(1);
    let txt = this.add.text(0, 0, 'click');
    Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(txt, btn, );

    let graphics = this.add.graphics({
      x: 750,
      y: 550
    });
    var shape = new Phaser.Geom.Circle(0, 0, 24);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000, 1);
    graphics.fillCircleShape(shape);
    //Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(graphics, btn);
  }
}

var config = {
  width: 800,
  height: 600,
  backgroundColor: '#555',
  scene: [BootScene]
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

There are 3 visual parts in the code above: the `btn` rectangle, the `txt` text and the `graphics`.

`Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center` works well with `btn` and `txt`.

`graphics` works well with `btn` using

```
this.add.graphics({
      x: 750,
      y: 550
    });
```

However, if I uncomment the following line below out

```
Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(graphics, btn);
```

the `graphics` is gone, not matter I set the config as `{ x: 750, y: 550 }` or `{ x: 0, y: 0 }`.

What am I missing?

---

I know I could use something like

```
let circle2 = this.add.circle(0, 0, 32, 0xf00000);
Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(btn_circle, circle2);
```

I'd just like to know why it doesn't work when I combine `graphics` and `Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center` together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Update:** it seems to be a bug of phaser *(or a mistake in the documentation)*, since after calling `Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center` on the graphics object, the `x` and `y` properties are set to `NaN`, and acording the documenation `Align` should accept a GameObject, which the `Graphics` object is.

**Here is a possible solution:**

- You could simply generate a texture out of the `graphics` object, with the function `generateTexture` on the `graphics` object
- *Align* the newly created image with the `btn`
- *I just added a `setDepth` call to the `txt` object, so it would be visible*

```js
class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({
      key: 'BootScene'
    });
  }
  create() {
    let btn = this.add.rectangle(300, 175, 200, 150, '#000').setOrigin(1);
    let txt = this.add.text(0, 0, 'click');
    Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(txt, btn );

    let graphics = this.make.graphics({
      x: 24,
      y: 24,
    });
    var shape = new Phaser.Geom.Circle(24, 24, 24);
    graphics.fillStyle(0xff0000, 1);
    graphics.fillCircleShape(shape);
        
    graphics.generateTexture('gCircle', 48, 48);
    let image = this.add.image(200, 200, 'gCircle');
    Phaser.Display.Align.In.Center(image, btn);

    // only to make the Button visible
    txt.setDepth(2);
            
  }
}

var config = {
  width: 400,
  height: 200,
  backgroundColor: '#555',
  scene: [BootScene]
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```